# Django POST issue

Tags: django

I' ve been struggling with this for a while:

I've create a Django App and have these models:

- Seasons
- Participants
- Objectives
- Partic_Obj
- Movements_Obj

"Partic_Obj" is the table that join "Participants" and "Seasons".

"Movements_Obj" is the table that i can't populate and should be containing the next data:

When you add a participant, it need to create automatically one register in "Movements_Obj", **for every objetive that corresponds to the season the participant is in**. For example: A participant is included in Season 1, which has 5 objectives, then, when i add this participant to "Partic_Obj" i need the 5 registers to be created automatically in "Movements_Obj".

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the logic of automatic creation of `Movements_obj` to the `save()` method of the `Participant` class.

Here is a link that might help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    do_something()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
    do_something_else()
```